# Cambiar propiedades de texto si este se desborda de su contenedor o padre css

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo un texto en html y php que varia de longitud según su contenido, el cual proviene de una base de datos mysql.

En ocasiones este texto se desborda de su contenedor o padre.

Lo que necesito es detectar cuando el texto se desborda para así asignarle propiedades especificas en css.

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo

Comment: Sin ejemplo no se puede dar una respuesta concreta ya que es muy ambiguo. Pero bueno, con PHP puro, si la cadena se pasa más de una longitud, por ejemplo: `$txtlimit = 80;` puedes usar `mb_substr($la_cadena, 0, $txtlimit) . '...';` lo que corta el texto y le agrega 3 puntos suspensivos. Otra forma es midiendo la cadena [mb_strlen()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strlen.php) y si se pasa del límite, mandarle al html otro tamaño para el texto. Pero si usas templates MVC o renderizas con JS, la cosa puede variar mucho.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Puedes evitar que ese texto se corte y muestre 3 puntos suspensivos automáticamente sólo con CSS.

Esto se consigue aplicando la propiedad ***text-overflow: ellipsis;***. Pero esta sólo funcionará cuando también apliques ***overflow: hidden;*** y ***white-space: nowrap;***

```css
.elemento-padre {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="elemento-padre">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In scelerisque fermentum nunc id tempor. Phasellus nec mi pulvinar, pulvinar ipsum in, consectetur dui. Vestibulum convallis tortor nisl, at auctor erat condimentum ac. Praesent ut porta urna. Nulla porttitor, quam quis lacinia fermentum, ligula nisi convallis tellus, in volutpat risus enim porta tortor.
</div>
```

Espero haberte ayudado ;)